# How can I ensure that two divs always have the same height?

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-mobile

I am using jquery-mobile framework. I have two `div`s side by side (as columns), I am trying to keep their height same irrespective of how much data they contain.

This the html:

```
  <ul class="datablock" id="Manufacturing_and_Qualification_Information" style="display: none;">    
 <div data-role="controlgroup" data-theme="d" class="ui-grid-m ui-corner-all ui-controlgroup ui-controlgroup-vertical">  
     <div data-theme="d" id="paramBlk" class="ui-block-m"><li>Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah</li></div> 
     <div data-theme="d" id="valueBlk" class="ui-block-n"><li>Blah</li></div>
</div>  
<div data-role="controlgroup" data-theme="d" class="ui-grid-m ui-corner-all ui-controlgroup ui-controlgroup-vertical">  
    <div class="ui-block-m" id="leftBtmRnd"><li>Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah</li></div> 
    <div class="ui-block-n" id="rightBtmRnd"><li>Blah</li></div>
</div>
</ul>
```

This is the jQuery code, which I tried so for, but it's not working as expected:

```
var $blockM = $(".datablock").find('.ui-block-m');  
    var $blockN = $(".datablock").find('.ui-block-n');                  
     if($blockM.height() < $blockN.height()){       
        $blockM.css('height',$blockN.height());        
    }else if($blockM.height() > $blockN.height()){   

        $blockN.css('height',$blockM.height());       
    }
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Use a table for displaying data in a table?

Comment: Why do you have `div` tags directly contained inside a `ul`?

Comment: As i said it's a mobile application...so i need to show the data in ul li format..

Comment: @James Khoury: using `table` bumped back to **taboo** for no logical reason after having been overused for years. Apparently "tableless" is now considered a feature (no idea why).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Working link : http://jsfiddle.net/bMMpz/1/

Here is the code:

```
var biggestHeight = 0;
var $blockM;
var $blockN;

$(function() {
    $blockM = $(".datablock").find('.ui-block-m');
    $blockN = $(".datablock").find('.ui-block-n');

    getBiggestHeight();

    $blockN.height(biggestHeight);
    $blockM.height(biggestHeight);
});



function getBiggestHeight() {
    $blockM.each(function(i, e) {
        if ($(e).height() > biggestHeight) biggestHeight = $(e).height()
    });
    $blockN.each(function(i, e) {
        if ($(e).height() > biggestHeight) biggestHeight = $(e).height()
    });
}
```

I look for the biggest div and then select both selector and set height.

Comment: There is no really no need to have methods and variables outside the DOM-ready method, you can just use it as a private variables inside methods, and getBiggestHeight could be a more general method if he wants to add more items: http://jsfiddle.net/bMMpz/2/

Comment: thanks buddy..it's working fine...but i encounter with 1 more problem..when i resize the window content inside div getting displayed outside...how can i fix this problem..

Comment: you can try clear:both and/or display:block on your divs, in your css. No probs bro

Comment: actually it happens for longer word..like `blahblahblahblah`...then it goes out side of div, other wise if i am having space in between words it wrapping properly

Comment: display:block or inline-block?

Comment: It needs some sort of white space, break in a word to indent it to the next line... otherwise add , overflow:hidden; , to your div property. http://jsfiddle.net/bMMpz/3/

Comment: `overflow:hidden; ` will simply hide the overflow content..but i want to show it but in next line..

Comment: What you can do is, check how many characters your div allows before overflowing... then read the div's html and insert breaks where need be. should be simple adding breaks to inner content text. :) hope you manage buddy. cheerz

Answer (score 1):

We use a jquery plugin (I guess) called 'equalheights' For this. There seem to be several out there, but they all seem to do the same job. (I'v not picked this one in our project, so I don't know exactly which it is we use, but they seem somewhat equal)

Take a look at [this plugin](http://www.cssnewbie.com/equalheights-jquery-plugin/) or [this plugin](http://www.filamentgroup.com/lab/setting_equal_heights_with_jquery/), I think they do what you want.

Comment: it's not good to use plugin for such a small thing...i can say that it's just a matter of 4 to 5 line jquery code..

Comment: Can you actually give reasons for that? The plugin is very small to, it's just a matter of where you get your code from: the function you declare, or the one you load. It is a micro-optimization to think that the "plugin" (it's just a function really) will take more time. And seeing that it takes SO several tries to get this right, why re-invent the wheel? You can even just copy the code if it makes you feel better, but there's no real reason for that.

Answer (score 1):

```
function equalHeight(group) {
    tallest = 0;
    group.each(function() {
    thisHeight = $(this).height();
    if(thisHeight > tallest) {
    tallest = thisHeight;
    }
    });

    group.height(tallest);

    }
    $(document).ready(function() {
    equalHeight($(".ui-grid-m"));
    });
```

Or use css3

```
.datablock
{ display:table;
}
.ui-grid-m
{  display:table-cell;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 if($blockM.height() < $blockN.height())
{               
    $blockM.height($blockN.height());             
}else if($blockM.height() > $blockN.height())
{  
   $blockN.height($blockM.height()); 
}
```

try this

Answer (score 0):

**Two column grids**

```
<div class="ui-grid-a">
    <div class="ui-block-a"><strong>I'm Block A</strong> and text inside will wrap</div>
    <div class="ui-block-b"><strong>I'm Block B</strong> and text inside will wrap</div>
</div>
```

[Just look in jQuery Mobile](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0b3/docs/content/content-grids.html)

Comment: As you can see in my html mark-up that i have used same classes as written in jquery mobile link..

Comment: But you have wrapped with UL and then used LI for content display.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function({
    var x = $('#primary').height();
    $('#sidebar').css('height', x);
});
```

Hope this helps.